# ArrayList of ArrayLists is overridden when setting values of a second one

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a battleship game, and this is the part where the players set their boards. When the second player to set the board makes theirs, the first player's board becomes the same as the second player's (when playing the game guessing the locations of that board are misses though, but that's another problem that will hopefully be fixed once this is). For example if I set the first player's ships as being at A1 A2 A3, B1 B2 B3, and C1 C2 C3, then set the second player's ships as D1 D2 D3, E1 E2 E3, and F1 F2 F3, when both lists of ships are printed out I get D1 D2 D3, E1 E2 E3, and F1 F2 F3 for both ships. I've found other questions on here with the same problem, but they always had the problem because they didn't make new lists every time, which I do (at least I'm pretty sure I do), so I can't find where my problem is. Here is the entire main game class, the GetShipLocations, SetShipLocations, and PlayersMakeTheirBoards, functions are what are giving me problems.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class MainGame {
    InputReader read = new InputReader();
    Grid p1Board = new Grid();
    Grid p2Board = new Grid();
    Grid p1ShipsBoard = new Grid();
    Grid p2ShipsBoard = new Grid();
    ArrayList<Ship> p1Ships = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    ArrayList<Ship> p2Ships = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    String activePlayer = "P1";

    public void SetUp() {
        p1Board.PrepPrintGrid();
        p2Board.PrepPrintGrid();
        Ship ship1 = new Ship();
        Ship ship2 = new Ship();
        Ship ship3 = new Ship();
        p1Ships.add(ship1);
        p1Ships.add(ship2);
        p1Ships.add(ship3);
        p2Ships.add(ship1);
        p2Ships.add(ship2);
        p2Ships.add(ship3);
    }
    public void GameIntro() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to battleship!");
        String rulesOption = read.getUserInput("Do you need to see the rules?");
        if(rulesOption.equals("Yes") || rulesOption.equals("yes"))
        {
            System.out.println("Put rules here");
        }
        System.out.println("Randomly determining which player goes first");
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        if(random == 1)
        {
            activePlayer = "P2";
        }
        System.out.println(activePlayer + " starts!");
    }
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> GetShipLocations(Grid board) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ships = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> ship1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ship2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ship3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ships.add(ship1);
        ships.add(ship2);
        ships.add(ship3);
        String[] numbers = {"first", "second", "third"};
        board.PrepPrintGrid();
        board.PrintGrid();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                String coordinate = read.getUserInput("Enter the " + numbers[j] + " coordinate of your " + numbers[i] + " ship (3 long):");
                ships.get(i).add(coordinate);
                board.SetGridDisplay(coordinate, "hit");
                board.PrintGrid();
            }
        }
        return ships;
    }
    public void SetShipLocations(ArrayList<Ship> ship, Grid activeBoard) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> shipLocations = GetShipLocations(activeBoard);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ship.get(i).SetCells(shipLocations.get(i));
        }
    }
    public void PlayersMakeTheirBoards() {
        if(activePlayer.equals("P1")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hand the computer to player one.");
            System.out.println("Player one, time to set your board.");
            SetShipLocations(p1Ships, p1ShipsBoard);//the effects of this seem to maybe be overriden when the second board is set
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p1Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Hand the computer to player two.");
            System.out.println("Player two, time to set your board.");
            SetShipLocations(p2Ships, p2ShipsBoard);
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p2Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p1Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Hand the computer to player two.");
            System.out.println("Player two, time to set your board.");
            SetShipLocations(p2Ships, p2ShipsBoard);
            /*for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }*/
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p2Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Hand the computer to player one.");
            System.out.println("Player one, time to set your board.");
            SetShipLocations(p1Ships, p1ShipsBoard);
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p1Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < /*100*/3; i++) 
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(p2Ships.get(i).cells.get(j));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public void PlayTheGame() {
        String guess = new String();
        String result = new String();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        while(!p1Ships.isEmpty() && !p2Ships.isEmpty())
        {
            if(activePlayer.equals("P1"))
            {
            //print the grid
            p1Board.PrintGrid();
            //ask user for their guess
            guess = read.getUserInput("Player one, enter your guess:");
            for(Ship boat:p2Ships)
            {
                result = boat.CheckYourself(guess);
                if(result.equals("hit"))
                {
                    System.out.println(result + "!");
                    break;
                }
                if(result.equals("kill"))
                {
                    System.out.println(result + "!");
                    p2Ships.remove(boat);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(result.equals("miss"))
            {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            p1Board.SetGridDisplay(guess, result);
            activePlayer = "P2";
            }
            else
            {
            p2Board.PrintGrid();
            //ask user for their guess
            guess = read.getUserInput("Player two, enter your guess:");
            for(Ship boat:p1Ships)
            {
                result = boat.CheckYourself(guess);
                if(result.equals("hit"))
                {
                    System.out.println(result + "!");
                    break;
                }
                if(result.equals("kill"))
                {
                    System.out.println(result + "!");
                    p1Ships.remove(boat);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(result.equals("miss"))
            {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            p2Board.SetGridDisplay(guess, result);
            activePlayer = "P1";
            }
        }
    }
    public void EndTheGame() {
        String winner = new String();
        if(p1Ships.isEmpty()) 
        {
            winner = "Player two";
            p2Board.PrintGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            winner = "Player one";
            p1Board.PrintGrid();
        }
        System.out.println("The game is over!");
        System.out.println(winner + " wins! Congratulations!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGame game = new MainGame();
        game.SetUp();
        game.GameIntro();
        game.PlayersMakeTheirBoards();
        game.PlayTheGame();
        game.EndTheGame();
    }
}
```

and here is the Ship class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ship {
    ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String name = new String();
    public void SetCells(ArrayList<String> locations) {
        cells = locations;
    }
    /*public void SetName(String word) {
        name = word;
    }*/
    public String CheckYourself(String guess) {
            if(cells.contains(guess)) 
            {
                cells.remove(guess);
                if(cells.isEmpty()) 
                {
                    return "kill";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "hit";
                }
            }
            return "miss";
    }
}
```

The grid and reader classes are working perfectly so I didn't include them.
(This is all based off the dotcom battleship game in headfirst java)

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names and variabele names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I always used to do that but in the book I noticed they used capitals for the first word too, I'll switch back

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make it clearer what exactly is the problem you are facing? I couldn't understand what you are trying to say because there is no clear description of the problem rather other side stories too.

Comment: How are you instantiating the p1Ships, p2Ships, p1ShipsBoard, p2ShipsBoard?

Comment: Also, since you're getting misses when targeting the same locations, are you sure your printing code is correct?

Comment: @B0b1 That's only for *class names*. They are written in PascalCase. So things like `ArrayList`, `String`, `Grid` and `Ship` are all starting with capitals. But method and variable names should be in camelCase (i.e. `checkYourself`, `setShipLocations`, et cetera).

Comment: Oh I see, I hadn't heard that before, thanks!

Comment: @afghanimah They're instance variables, which is realize now is probably not what they should be

Comment: @Kapil I added an example of what is happening that is wrong, hopefully that clears it up

Comment: @B0b1 No, like how/where are you doing `ArrayList<> p1Ships = ...`?

Comment: @afghanimah I just put in the entire class so you can see everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setup function:

```
public void SetUp() {
        p1Board.PrepPrintGrid();
        p2Board.PrepPrintGrid();
        Ship ship1 = new Ship();
        Ship ship2 = new Ship();
        Ship ship3 = new Ship();
        p1Ships.add(ship1);
        p1Ships.add(ship2);
        p1Ships.add(ship3);
        p2Ships.add(ship1);
        p2Ships.add(ship2);
        p2Ships.add(ship3);
    }
```

You are adding the same instances of ship1-3 to both p1Ships and p2Ships.  So when you change the ships of player 2, the p1Ships ArrayList is still pointing to the same ships as p2Ships, and thus will always be the same.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed this, thank you so much. What a dumb mistake haha